# How to route traffic through an intermediate local interface?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, routing, linux-networking

I have an Ubuntu server with 3 NICs:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                             |
|  ---------------      ---------------      ---------------  |
|  |     eth0    |      |     eth1    |      |     eth2    |  |
|  | 192.168.1.2 |      | 192.168.5.1 |      | 192.168.5.2 |  |
|  |     (gw)    |      |             |      |             |  |
|  ---------------      ---------------      ---------------  |
|        ▒▒                     ▒▒                   ▒▒       |
---------▒▒---------------------▒▒-------------------▒▒--------
         ▒▒                     ▒▒                   ▒▒
       router                   ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
     192.168.1.1

▒▒  - wire
```

**NIC names and IP addresses were changed for ease of perception*

**eth0** and **eth1** are built-in NICs, **eth2** is a heaped up PCI NIC, for which I am writing a low-level code.
To do this, I have to receive/send all packets from/to certain IP addresses via **eth2** along the route:

`eth2 <==> [eth1 ~~~~ eth0] <==> router <==> ISP`

Such a connection scheme, if feasible, is needed in order to dump all traffic on **eth1** to/from **eth2**, because **eth2** runs outside the Linux network stack and cannot be sniffed by Wireshark.

Is there a way to organize such routing?

**There is no:**

- way to connect **eth2** directly to the router and dump on the router side.
- access to router at all.
- way to add another switch/router/PC between **eth0** and **eth2**.

As far as I understand, the solution is somewhere in `ip route ... table local` but I am unable to figure out which rules to add and which to delete.

Comment: `eth2 runs outside the Linux network stack` In that case you just make `192.168.5.1` the default gateway of `192.168.5.2`? What does local route even have to with it then? (Maybe I'm being naive. No idea what "heaped up PCI NIC" is or what kind of "low level code" or "outside" your are talking about. I could only imagine `eth1` and `eth2` (and the wire between them) is *like* a veth pair and `eth2` is *like* in another network namespace.)

Comment: @TomYan you're kinda right, using netns is the simplest way to isolate **eth2**. but it comes with a penalty that I am unable to use NICs from different namespaces.

`runs outside the Linux network stack` means that every physical packet what comes from wire to **eth2** is handled by my code instead of Linux kernel (i.e. I've reimplemented ARP, ICMP, IGMP, UDP, TCP etc)

Comment: What I meant was, if you can even see `eth2` on `ip l` (or put it into a netns), it doesn't really sound like it's "outside the Linux network stack", at least not entirely. What I expected for "outside the Linux network stack" is that the NIC would **already be like** in a netns. To be honest, it sounds out of the scope of this site as well (and no one knows how exactly you "reimplemented" stuff anyway). But maybe you can try `ip rule` and extra route table, like have a default route that uses `eth0` in one and look it up only for traffics from `eth1`, while `eth2` stays in the main table.

Comment: But to be frank, I am not even sure how would stuff be like when you have such a "loopback connection", even if you do NOT have stuff "reimplemented".